# Firebase Auth createUserWithEmailAndPassword in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having some issues with Firebase Auth creating a user in my react app.

The other functions, sign-in, sign-out, password reset all work fine with the same Firebase account. Just sign up isn't working.

I have a form on the sign up page which when submitted does the following:

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefaualt();
    const email = emailRef.current.value;
    const name = nameRef.current.value;
    const password = passwordRef.current.value;
    if(email && name && password) registerUser(email, name, password);
  };
```

This then starts this:

```
    const registerUser = (email, name, password) => {
        const id = user.userUID
        setLoading(true);
        setUID(id);
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(() => {
            return updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                displayName: name,
                email: email,
                userUID: id
            });
        })
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .then(() => (window.location.pathname = `/subscriptions`))
        .catch((err) => setError(err.message))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
```

My understanding is that this should create a new user in firebase?

Comment: What error do you get? The user isn't created at all? Also the `updateProfile()` does not take userUID as a param. You cannot update the UID once user is created.

Comment: No error, just nothing happens and a user isn't created at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateProfile()` can be used to update `displayName` and `photoURL` only. If you want to update email then you must use `updateEmail()`. However, that's not required here as you are creating user account with same email.

Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = emailRef.current.value;
  const name = nameRef.current.value;
  const password = passwordRef.current.value;

  if (email && name && password) {
    registerUser(email, name, password).then(() => {
      console.log("User created")
    })
  };
};


const registerUser = async (email, name, password) => {
  try {
    console.log("> Registering user")
    setLoading(true);
    const {
      user
    } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

    console.log("> Updating profile")
    await updateProfile(user, {
      displayName: name,
    });

    window.location.pathname = `/subscriptions`;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  setLoading(false)
}
```

---

You cannot update user's UID once created. If you want to set a custom UID to user while creating then you need to use the Admin SDK. Checkout: [Custom Uid In Firebase CreateUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035814/custom-uid-in-firebase-createuser)